# Reposition div within Columns using React-Bootstrap's grid layout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I am working with React-Bootstrap's Grid layout functionality, and am struggling mightily with moving a div around depending on the width of the screen / how the div would fit best.

Here is the React-Bootstrap code for this...

```
<Row>
    <Col>
        <img src={rocketslogo.url}/>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={8}>
        <div>
            {teamSelect}
        </div>
        <div>
            {yearsSelect}
        </div>
        <div>
            {teamStatsAndInfo}
        </div>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={12}>
        {teamStatsAndInfo}
    </Col>
</Row>
```

I am currently displaying the `teamStatsAndInfo` twice to show what desired effect I would like, which is - When the width is wider, I would like the `teamStatsAndInfo` div to be placed *below* the selects. However, when the width is more narrow, I would like the `teamStatsAndInfo` div to be placed below the logo and the selects.

...because the team's logo gets smaller whereas the selects stay the same size, it makes sense to move the team's stats and info as its own column below both the logo and the selects, however I am not sure how to conditionally do this.

I am new to building things mobile-first and am struggling with building a responsive layout. I'm not sure if I am breaking many best-practices rules (shrinking logo with same-sized selects, how to use  within Cols, etc.). Any thoughts or help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you fork them in a stackblitz??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- First Step when you start with a mobile friendly site is to come up with a wireframe for all the diff screen sizes.

-- in ur code you have assigned `Col xs={8}` for the data column. you need to set the widths for other screen sizes also. eg: md - medium screens(≥992px), sm- small screens (≥768px)  and so on.Also you can hide some fields in the small screen using xsHidden (hide columns in extra small devices)

For more details in the column sizes refer the docs,

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/

Thanks hope it helps.

Comment: I knew about xsPush and xsOffset, but did not know about xsHidden. This will be helpful thank you!